# How to preserve types after partially applying function parameters in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some functions, and I want to partially apply the first argument to all of them.  A simplified example:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const funcs = {                                                                     
  add: (a: number, b: number) => {                                                  
    return a + b                                                                    
  },                                                                                
  multiply: (a: number, ...rest: number[]) => {                                     
    let total = a                                                                   
    for (const num of rest) {                                                       
      total = total * num                                                           
    }                                                                               
    return total                                                                    
  },                                                                                
}                                                                                   

const result = _.mapValues(funcs, func => _.partial(func, 1))
```

That partly does what I want: typescript knows that result.add is a function that takes one number, for instance.

However, it thinks that result.multiply is a function that takes a one number rather than a variable number of numbers (I believe due to limitations in lodash's typescript support).  Even without that limitation, I want to do this in the context of a function (because in my actual codebase, partially applying the functions is just one step of many).  Something like this:

```
// does NOT work as desired
function doPartials<                                                                
  F extends {[funcName: string]: (arg1: number, ...rest: any[]) => any}             
>(funcs: F) {                                                                       
  const newFuncs = _.mapValues(funcs, func => _.partial(func, 1))                   
  return newFuncs                                                                   
}                                                                                   

const result2 = doPartials(funcs)
```

That doesn't do what I want.  Typescript thinks that result2.add and result2.multiply take any[] and returns an any.  I think I need the parameters of doPartials to enforce that each function takes a number as its first parameter (or else typescript would error out on the mapValues call), but I can't figure out how to do that in a way that will preserve the types of the rest of the parameters and of the return value.

Is there a way to change doPartials so that it doesn't discard all of the type information for the provided functions?

Comment: In your first example `typescript` does not recognize `multiple` take several parameters but 1 !

Comment: Good call!  Will edit my question to reflect that.